# Аналоги background-image

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: скриншот]

Верстаю сайт. Нужно поместить цифры 01 как на скриншоте. Есть ли какие-нибудь методики, кроме использования background-image?

Comment: Через :before{content="01"}

Comment: А чем background-image не подходит? Когда картинка не смысловая - лучше ложить ещё background-ом

Answer (score 4):

Пример

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.b-articles {
    counter-reset: countArticle;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.b-article {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
}
.b-article:before {    
    content: counter(countArticle, decimal-leading-zero) " "; 
    counter-increment: countArticle;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section class="b-articles">
    <article class="b-article">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque justo dui, maximus eget venenatis quis, euismod at sem. Nulla sodales est nec elementum efficitur. Ut non egestas justo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada</p>
    </article>
    <article class="b-article">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque justo dui, maximus eget venenatis quis, euismod at sem. Nulla sodales est nec elementum efficitur. Ut non egestas justo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada</p>
    </article>
    <article class="b-article">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque justo dui, maximus eget venenatis quis, euismod at sem. Nulla sodales est nec elementum efficitur. Ut non egestas justo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно разместить блок с цифрами под блоком с контентом. Для этого у блока с цифрами нужно установить `position: absolute`, а у блока с контентом `position: relative`. Пример:

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
}

.section:before {
  content: '01';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 80px;
  opacity: .1
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>About us</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque justo dui, maximus eget venenatis quis, euismod at sem. Nulla sodales est nec elementum efficitur. Ut non egestas justo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
      fames ac turpis egestas. Cras eget dui vel magna tincidunt malesuada. Maecenas porttitor mauris mi, vehicula egestas justo consequat a. Quisque facilisis felis eget ultrices varius. Curabitur lacinia placerat consectetur. Vestibulum venenatis nunc
      in rhoncus malesuada. Phasellus vel pharetra elit. Vivamus vitae imperdiet lorem, non euismod ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавить img тегом , а текст что идет поверх на `position absolute`.
Как вариант.